# WindowsCryptographicException: 'Cannot find the requested object' when creating X509Certificate2 from byte array in .net standard 2 project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a `pem` file containing only public key like below

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>   MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAl1bkU0KO3GSavjS+Dzxk
>   dTewQ7GNXzsXComZQECvNNiZ8RFL+wmXBu4iu49gXjzAWF2EtcAqr6Xe3L+2H8/5
>   7OmtYXttTFTJl+8ZSG0Jk+i8Pz51a6LZtN9oBv/coX+TL3yIPTrjm4TXC+MLexhx
>   vwIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Then I am trying to create `X509Certificate2` from it, so I concated the key and convert it to byte array and then passing it to `X509Certificate2` constructor , but I get `WindowsCryptographicException: 'Cannot find the requested object'` exception

I tried different overloads of `new X509Certificate2` but same result.

```
var rsaKey = Convert.FromBase64String("MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAl1bkU0KO3GavjS+DzxkdTewQ7GNXzsXComZQECvNNiZ8RFL+wmXBu4iu49gXjzAWF2EtcAqr6Xe3L+2H8/57OmtYXtTFTJl+8ZSG0Jk+i8Pz51a6LZtN9oBv/coX+TL3yIPTrjm4TXC+MLexhxvwIDAQAB");

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(rsaKey);

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(rsaKey, "");

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(rsaKey, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

I found some posts on stackoverflow, and none of them was working (so please don't mark it as duplicate)

My project is `.net standard 2.0.3`

Comment: Same here and it sucks.

Comment: Same problem, any suggestion will helps!